# c# threads notify user if any of the tasks does not complete within a timespan

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have three tasks

```
        List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var Task1 = HeavyWorkAsync();
        var Task2 = HeavyWorkAsync();
        var Task3 = HeavyWorkAsync();

        TaskList.Add(Task1);
        TaskList.Add(Task2);
        TaskList.Add(Task3);
```

And i want to update a label on my WPF application if any of the tasks does not complete within XX seconds.

I tried using combination of WhenAny and WhenAll like this:

```
Task t = await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(TaskList), Task.Delay(8000));
label.Content = "Work is still being done";
Console.WriteLine("Regular Stopwatch: {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

but i cannot make it to work

The Async Methods:

```
    private Random m_Random = new Random();

    public void HeavyWork() {
        double secondsToSleep = m_Random.NextDouble() * 10;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToSleep));
    }

    public Task HeavyWorkAsync() {
        return Task.Run(() => HeavyWork());
    }
```

Comment: So? What's the problem? Are you getting exceptions? Swallowing exceptions? Does the UI update too late? What actually happens? And what are those `HeavyWorkAsync` methods doing? Unless they are truly asynchronous, you're out of luck - if you call the methods, do they return *immediately*? If not, the `Task.WhenAny` might simply happen too late to matter.

Comment: The ui does not update. I am using stopwatches and the timer goes beyond the timelimit, but the label is still not updated.

Comment: Okay. So what happens when you start the stopwatch *after* you start all those tasks? It's a pretty good bet that those "Async" methods you're calling simply aren't async (or they aren't async enough). `await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(TaskList), Task.Delay(8000))` works just fine - but it doesn't help you if a significant amount of time is spent in those `XXXAsync` methods.

Comment: I included the async method in the question.

Comment: Does the UI freeze while the tasks are running? Does the `label.Content = "Work is still being done";` line execute?

Comment: UI does not freeze and the label never changes to "work is still being done", even if i decrease the timespan to 1 second

Comment: But if you insert a breakpoint on that line, does it hit?

Comment: Can you show the complete method that contains the line `label.Content = "Work is still being done";`?

Comment: Solved. I had await Task.WhenAll(TaskList); on top of the Task.WhenAny(..). I swapped the two calls and now it works. Why this happened though?

Comment: Because the first await will prevent the code from continuing until all tasks are done.

Comment: By the way, you still need to check which task finished before deciding to change the label content

Comment: How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check which task finished first, the delay task or the `Task.WhenAll(TaskList)` task (the task that finishes when all the work is done). Here is an example:

```
var delay_task = Task.Delay(8000);
Task t = await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(TaskList), delay_task);

if (t == delay_task)
{
    label.Content = "Work is still being done";
}
else
{
    //Work finished before the timeout
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what about using Task.WaitAll(tasks, 10000)?